# Formatting data ingested into Azure SQL Database

Tags: sql, azure, azure-sql-database

Currently I'm importing a CSV file into an Azure SQL database automatically each morning at 3 am, but the file has several blank lines in the csv file that are imported as rows which is cleaned up after the data is ingested.

There isn't a way to correct the file prior to ingestion, so I need to transform the data once it's been ingested and would like to avoid having to do this manually.

Is using something like Azure Data Factory the best approach to doing this? Or is there a less expensive / simpler way to simply remove blank lines via something akin to a stored procedure for Azure SQL Database?

Comment: I have an Azure SQL database and it allows the use of stored procedures.   I think you can simply write the stored procedure and schedule it to run after your import job.